# Copy values from one excel file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to make a template sheet with data located in another file. I am wondering how I can copy the values into the template sheet without the formatting being disrupted.

I am very new to VBA so I'm sure there is a lot of redundancy and a more efficient way to accomplish this task. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PlatingSheet()


    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Workbooks.Open ("\\in-mmge-file\users\tbever\Desktop\VBA\Plating Sheets\Copy - 24605_17 QC Results and Notes.xlsx")
   Workbooks.Open ("\\in-mmge-file\users\tbever\Desktop\VBA\Plating Sheets\Copy - 1.1Unified_Plating_Template.xlsx")


    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Copy - 24605_17 Results and >Notes.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("B5:B96")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Copy - 1.1 >Fluidigm_Unified_Plating_Template.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("G4:G94").Past>eSpecial(xlPasteValues)

    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub PlatingSheet()

    Const FPATH As String = "\\in-mmge-file\users\tbever\Desktop\VBA\Plating Sheets\"

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & "Copy - 24605_17 QC Results and Notes.xlsx")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & "Copy - 1.1Unified_Plating_Template.xlsx")

    With wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("B5:B96")
        'assign the value directly
        wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("G4").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

What is about Power Query? You don't need any VBA for this and its very intuitive. And of course, you can refresh the data automatically - for example at opening the file. Just go on Excel to Data > Get External Data > From File > Excel.

Comment: I am not familiar with Power Query. I just watched a quick video on it and it looks pretty accessible. I'm pretty new to using VBA. I just assumed it was the best way to speed up doing repetitive tasks. Ultimately I would like to increase the complexity of the templates I'm creating above to be more dynamic. Thanks for the suggestions.